# Laravel - Passing a PHP resource to Storage::put

Tags: php, laravel, flysystem

The Laravel docs (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/filesystem#storing-files) state this:

> Storing Files
>   The put method may be used to store a file on disk. You may also pass a PHP resource to the put method, which will use Flysystem's underlying stream support. Using streams is greatly recommended when dealing with large files:
>       `Storage::put('file.jpg', $contents);`
>       `Storage::put('file.jpg', $resource);`

I am looking to save a file larger than my php memory limit (512MB), so when I do this, I get a memory error:

> FatalErrorException in Local.php line 128: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 377028088 bytes).

How do I use the streaming functionality as indicated in the docs? How do I go from a file path to a "PHP resource"?

Answer (score 3):

PHP is not allowing you to upload a file with that size. The resource that is being pointed out in the docs are this kind of [PHP resource](http://php.net/manual/en/resource.php)

Here's a simple example of creating an image from an external image URL using [Intervention](http://image.intervention.io/). The Intervention library uses the GD library, which is under the PHP resource list.

```
$image = Image::make('Your Extenal URL')->stream();
Storage::put('image_name.jpg', $image->getContents());
```

In your case, here's an example code on uploading a file.

```
$file = Request::file('file_field');
Storage::put($file->getClientOriginalName(), File::get($file));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fopen` with the path of the file that will give you the resource.

```
Storage::put('file.jpg', fopen($contentFilePath, 'r'));
```